# Merge Two json array in one in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have two json arrays like

```
var json1 = [{id:1, name: 'xxx' ...}]
var json2 = [{sec:'A', class_name:'xyz' ...}]
```

I want them merge in to single arrays

```
var finalObj = [{id:1, name: 'xxx' ...},{id:sec, name: class_name ...},{id:A, name: 'xyz' ...}... ]
```

Comment: You have two entries in the input and three entries in the output. How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both objects have a property with the same name, then the second object property overwrites the first. The best solution in this case is to use Lodash and its merge() method, which will perform a deeper merge, recursively merging object properties and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to concatinate two arrays into one.

```
var finalObj = json1.concat(json2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get this right as you have the properties of second array as values in the expected result, but if you want to merge both arrays you could use spread operator:

`var finalObj = [...json1, ...json2]`